# Distribution of the Square of the Minimum of Two Normal Variables

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

I was asked to prove that $Z^2 \sim \chi _1 ^2$ where $Z = \min (X,Y)$. Below is my working out:
$$  F_{\mathcal{Z}^2}(z)  := P(\mathcal{Z}^2 < z)$$
$$  = P(\mathcal{Z}^2 < z, X<Y) + P(\mathcal{Z}^2 < z, Y<X) $$
$$= P(\mathcal{Z}^2 < z | X<Y)\cdot P(X<Y) + P(\mathcal{Z}^2 < z | Y<X)\cdot P(Y<X)$$
$$= P(X^2 < z)\cdot \frac 12 + P(Y^2 < z)\cdot \frac 12$$
$$    = P(X^2 < z)\cdot \frac 12 + P(X^2 < z)\cdot \frac 12$$
$$    = P(X^2 < z)$$
$$= F_{X^2}(z)$$

My concern with my working out is with the second step. I am not sure that it is correct to split up the probability into the 2 cases where $X<Y$ and $Y<X$.

Comment: This was asked not long back.

Comment: @StubbornAtom could you please send a link to the question because I cant seem to find the question. Thanks

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2790910/321264.

Comment: @StubbornAtom thanks for the link. I see that a similar has been asked before, but I feel like my question is different since I am asking whether my specific solution is valid or not which is not covered in that question